# How to hide the message after hidden property is applied in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I have this piece of code in my html file.

```
<div class="form-group"
    [ngClass]="{'has-error': (countryVar.touched || countryVar.dirty) && !countryVar.valid }">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="firstNameId">
        Country
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" 
            id="countryId" 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Country (required)" 
            required 
            [(ngModel)]=customer.country
            name="country"
            #countryVar="ngModel" />
            <span class="help-block" [hidden]="countryVar.touched">           
                Please enter your country.
            </span>                           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically what I want to achieve is that after touched is true the message "Please enter your country " to be hidden. 
 How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where you set the countryVar.touched to true?

Comment: your code is fine and the message will be hidden if `touched` is true

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine I found the mistake. The bootstrap class "help-block" has a display property set to inline-block. When I delete this class then it works

Comment: @Dea good job .